# Ansible: when list in list

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have two lists:

```
a:
 - 1
 - 2 
 - 3
b: 
 - 2
 - 3
 - 4
```

I need to run a task only when any of items in `a` is contained in `b`. How is this possible?

```
tasks:
  - name: one of elements of a in b
    debug: msg=At least one of elements of a is contained in b
    when: ???
```

Comment: prehaps use the `{}` button in the question entry box to format your code? (you can edit your question)  I'm very confused to the structure of your dicts, if they are like `a = {1,2,3}` that is actually a `set`.

Comment: It looks like you have two lists.

Comment: For me , It's realy unclear what you are asking !

Comment: I meant lists of course, sorry. Too tired after the day.

Answer (score 5):

Ansible has the `intersect` filter, which will return elements which are contained in two lists. ([See docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters))

```
{{ a | intersect(b) }}
```

The result would be a list containing the elements `2` and `3`.

In your condition then simply check the length of that resulting list:

```
tasks:
  - name: one of elements of a in b
    debug: msg=One of elements of a is contained in b
    when: "{{ a | intersect(b) | length > 0 }}"
```

*Update:* for modern Ansible syntax `{{` and `}}` in when statements must be omitted:

```
tasks:
  - name: one of elements of a in b
    debug: msg=One of elements of a is contained in b
    when: a | intersect(b) | length > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!